# JavaScript - Regex split string to array allowing for apostrophes

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, match

I have some Express middleware which handles a string - a sentence entered by a user through a text field - and does some analysis on it.  For this I need both the words and the punctuation broken into an array.

An example string is:

```
"It's familiar. Not much has really changed, which is surprising, but 
it's nice to come back to where I was as a kid."
```

As part of the process I replace new lines with `<br />` and split the string into an array

```
res.locals.storyArray = 
res.locals.story.storyText.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, ' <br/>' ).split(" ");
```

this works to a certain degree but when a sentence contains an apostrophe e.g. `"It's familiar.` things get thrown out of sync and I get an array like (note that there is detail I'm not showing here regarding how the word gets mapped to its grammar type) :

```
[ [ '"', 'quote' ],
['It', 'Personal pronoun' ], <--these items are the issue
[ '\'', 'quote' ],   < --------these items are the issue
[ 's', 'Personal pronoun'],  <------these items are the issue
[ 'familiar', 'Adjective' ],
[ '.', 'Sent-final punct' ],
[ 'Not', 'Adverb' ],
[ 'much', 'Adjective' ],
[ 'has', 'Verb, present' ],
[ 'really', 'Adverb' ],
[ 'changed', 'verb, past part' ],
[ ',', 'Comma' ],
[ 'which', 'Wh-determiner' ],
[ 'is', 'Verb, present' ]]
```

I'm actually surprised that the commas and full stops seem to be split correctly seeing I am only splitting on white space but I'm trying to get my array to be:

```
[ [ '"', 'quote' ],
[ 'It's, 'Personal pronoun' ],
[ 'familiar', 'Adjective' ],
[ '.', 'Sent-final punct' ],
.....
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `String.raw` to make sure the string remains correctly in-tact with included punctuation.

The only issue I had was in keeping the "." punctuation marks. For that I added a new replace function before splitting `.replace(/\./g, " .")` - this was done for all commas as well.

```
let strArray = myStr.replace(/\./g, " .")
  .replace(/\,/g, " ,")
  .replace(/\"/g, String.raw` " `)
  .split(/\s/g)
  .filter(_=>_);
```

```js
let myStr = String.raw `"It's familiar. Not much has really changed, which is surprising, but
it's nice to come back to where I was as a kid."`;
let strArray = myStr.replace(/\./g, " .")
  .replace(/\,/g, " ,")
  .replace(/\"/g, String.raw` " `)
  .split(/\s/g)
  .filter(_=>_);

let HTML = myStr.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, " <br/>");
console.log(myStr);
console.log(strArray);
```

EDIT: Added `replace` for comma separation as well.

I'm not sure what you expect to be done about the `<br/>` - it seems silly to insert them while trying to turn your string into an array. In the code I've separated the process. You now have a string that spits out with `<br/>` tags and another variable that contains the array.

If you have any supplemental information, if this doesn't solve your issue, I'd be happy to help

Comment: Many thanks for this, looks good. The <br /> are my attempt to preserve line breaks the user enters in the text input when their content is presented on the page.  I'll work your solution into my app when I get back from work but I'm pretty sure I'll mark your answer as the correct one.  Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, thanks agains for this. I just tested it and there is still an issue caused by the speech marks.  The example string I gave shows `"It's familiar ` but the example string you have is ``It's familiar` (which is actually another valid case I hadn't covered).  However when I run your solution the array returned is `[ '"It\'s', 'familiar', '.', 'Not', 'much',` but I'd like to get to `['"', 'It\'s', 'familiar', '.', 'Not', 'much',` i.e. the speech marks `"` (but it could also be the single quote mark I guess as you have) should be an array item by itself.

Comment: wow, that's perfect.  Many thanks, I would never have got there!